# Manage string content with HTML tags in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have this array that contains a message for a user. This is contained  in variable `$arr` which is an array.

`$arr` looks like this when using `var_dump()`

[image: var_dump($arr)]

What I want to do is to merge the tables in `[0]` and `[1]` and have a result like this.

[image: aim result]

Please mention the things that I missed or you want to know. Any idea/s would be really appreciated!

Comment: So you basically want to de-duplicate the text?

Comment: De-duplicate, meaning merging the content? I apologize for not getting what you mean.

Comment: Oh I see. It might be good to explain exactly what you want to accomplish in the body of your question. I had a hard time figuring out what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: @yowza can you post your php code how you are generating this HTML. It is quite hard to understand what you want to accomplish ..What I got is $message is a string that is having the table which will display the array data in a tabular format .bu want to see the array, can you var_dump the array outside the HTML table ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I apologize for the late response, I have updated my question. Please tell me what I'm still missing.

Comment: @yowza so key[0] and key[2] are two arrays ?? and there will be more like key[3], key[4] ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu It's just one array, with [0], [1] keys, and there will be more keys

Comment: @yowza key[0] contains { 1, fool, fool } ? if yes, is it an array or object ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu In my case, array([0]=>'Dear User...'), it's an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96846/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-yowza).

Comment: @yowza have you got your problem solved with that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To concatenate some rows in the same table, you have just to extract them from their original tables and them to a table which is concatenated with the common text parts. For that, take this example :

I'll put my texts in an array :

```
$data = [
    'Dear User2,<br> <br> Sample text <table style="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%" border="solid"> <tr> <th>TH1</th> <th>TH2</th> <th>TH3</th> </tr> <tr> <td style="width:10%"><center>1</center></td> <td style="width:20%"><center>foo1</center></td> <td style="width:20%"><center>foo1</center></td> </tr> </table> <br> Thank you, <br> Admin',
    'Dear User2,<br> <br> Sample text <table style="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%" border="solid"> <tr> <th>TH1</th> <th>TH2</th> <th>TH3</th> </tr> <tr> <td style="width:10%"><center>2</center></td> <td style="width:20%"><center>foo2</center></td> <td style="width:20%"><center>foo2</center></td> </tr> </table> <br> Thank you, <br> Admin',
    'Dear User2,<br> <br> Sample text <table style="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%" border="solid"> <tr> <th>TH1</th> <th>TH2</th> <th>TH3</th> </tr> <tr> <td style="width:10%"><center>3</center></td> <td style="width:20%"><center>foo3</center></td> <td style="width:20%"><center>foo3</center></td> </tr> </table> <br> Thank you, <br> Admin'
];
```

Common parts are :

```
Dear User2,<br> <br> Sample text <table style="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%" border="solid"> <tr> <th>TH1</th> <th>TH2</th> <th>TH3</th> </tr>
```

and

```
</table> <br> Thank you, <br> Admin
```

So if the common parts are always the same and with fixed lengths, you can use some `substr()` to extract what you need like this, for example :

```
// get common parts
$common_part_1 = substr($data[0], 0, 151);
$common_part_2 = substr($data[0], -36);

$content = '';

// concatenate all content rows
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){
    $content .= get_content($data[$i]);
}
```

where `get_content()` is the function that will extract the row containing the targeted text :

```
function get_content($data){    
    return substr($data, 151 , strlen($data) - 36 - 151);
}
```

then

```
echo $common_part_1 . $content . $common_part_2;
```

Of course this manner is really very limited, I don't recommend you to use it but I tried to give an idea how you can do ...

---

The second manner, is to extract your text using `regex` with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) function :

```
// extract the 1st content row  
$content = get_content($data[0]);

// extract the common parts
$common_parts = str_replace($content, '##content##', $data[0]);

// concatenate all content rows
for($i = 1; $i < count($data); $i++){
    $content .= get_content($data[$i]);
}
```

and

```
function get_content($data){
    $pattern = '/\<\/th\>\s\<\/tr\>(.*)\<\/table\>/';
    preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

then

```
echo str_replace('##content##', $content, $common_parts);
```

which will give you for both manners something like this :

[image]

Hope that can help.

Comment: very nice 2nd option :)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `$message` into multiple part.

```
$message = '
     Dear User {APPROVER_SL},<br>
     <br>
     Sample text
     <table style="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%" border="solid">
     <tr>
     <th>TH1</th>
     <th>TH2</th>
     <th>TH3</th>
     </tr>';

$max = 10 // Your number of lines
for($i =0; $i < $max ; $i++){
    $message .= '
        <tr>
           <td style="width:10%"><center>'.$i.'</center></td>
           <td style="width:20%"><center>foo'.$i.'</center></td>
           <td style="width:20%"><center>foo'.$i.'</center></td>
        </tr>';
}

$message .='
</table>
<br>
Thank you, <br>
{SYSTEM_NAME}';
```

Try to integrate CSS into the code too so that your code don't look so messy and easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the messy part, I'll integrate CSS into my code.

Comment: is the code working for you? Basically you should adjust the second part of the code to generate your data and input using a loop.

Comment: It works fine but I need to adjust the second part, just like what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code this is the sample code but you try this logic in that it will definitely help you thanx.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Array</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $arr = array
  (
  array("Upendrasinh",100,100),
  array("Ankit dave",200,200),
  array("Krunal Lathiya",300,300),
  array("Arjun Kanani",400,400),
  );

  $arrCount = count($arr);


  // $arrsubcount = count($arr[0]);
  // echo $arrsubcount;
  // echo "<br>";

  $arraycell=count($arr[0][0]);
  $arraycell=$arraycell;

echo '<table border="5px" width="100%">';
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Score</th>";
            echo "<th>Score2</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
  for($arrayrow=0;$arrayrow<=$arrCount-1;$arrayrow++){
            echo "<tr>"."<td>".$arr[$arrayrow][0]. "</td>"; 
                for($arraycolumn=0;$arraycolumn<$arraycell;$arraycolumn++){
                    echo "<td>".$arr[$arrayrow][$arraycell]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$arr[$arrayrow][$arraycell+1]."</td>"."</tr>";
                }
    }
  echo '</table>';

?>

</body>
</html>
```